# Gzip after exec() returns NULL

Tags: php, shell, exec, gzip

I am trying run CLI command via php function exec():

```
gzip -1 -c files/original/file.txt > files/compressed/gzip/1/file.txt.gz 2>&1
```

But file is not created and `var_dump()` prints `NULL`.
Chmod is set to `0777`. If I put this command to console (in path where is index.php and function exec()) everything is OK...

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Is the directory and the file accessible and writable for the PHP user?

Comment: There was not accessible. My settings have been ```chmod 0777``` only from ```index.php```. If I set ```chmod``` from root everything is OK. But maybe is not good idea set ```chmod 0777``` to directories where are scripts can you specify how i can chceck or set  accessible only for php user? (debian)

Comment: `chown www-data:www-data <directory>` will give owner rights to `www-user`. If you want to also include underlaying directories and files, use the option `-R`. If you run your web server for lots of different users, consider [Running PHP scripts as specific users with suphp](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/84/Running_PHP_scripts_as_specific_users_with_suphp).